# Is the postgis layer option in qgis 2.12 Lyon two way? Was the spit plugin built in?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins, spatial-database, postgis-2.0

I am trying to install Postgresql with Postgis on a remotely accessed terminal only installation of Ubuntu 14.04 that I want to use to connect to QGIS 2.12 and hopefully have a two way transfer between editing data and committing it to my database and grabbing it to edit.

If so, is there any known compatibility issues if I use Postgresql 9.5 and Postgis 2.1 given that QGIS 2.12 is only a month old?

Essentially, I would like to be able to edit data in QGIS and have a Postgis database connected to Geoserver for display.

Comment: I wouldn't expect any problems. While the release itself may be new, it has been in very active development since before postgres 9.2.